# kubernetes Liveness probe fail but only after a specific api call is executed

Tags: kubernetes

For the most part, my application executes with no problems. I got two environments with the same Kubernetes configuration and same code base. UAT and Prod.

In UAT I get no problem, but in PROD, I get the following:
[image]

This only happens after executing a specific endpoint. I've debugged the endpoints, and it executes correctly. It completes just fine, let me show, this is the network log from Firefox:
[image]

Now, after these endpoints calls are complete, there are no code errors in the pod. But then the Liveness Probe fails according to the following parameters:

```
    livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /
          port: http
        initialDelaySeconds: 60
        timeoutSeconds: 5
        failureThreshold: 6
```

So after 35 seconds, the pod is restarted. For some reason, the GET fails. But it only happens after calling that API.

At first, I thought the problem might be in the code. But the same code is in UAT, and it works with no problem. So now I think there might be something different in PROD K8s config. However, cannot find it, all probes config are the same for UAT and PROD.

And again, it only fails after calling this one API. It's very strange.

Any tips are welcome. Thanks.

UPDATE:

I did a test by pinging the localhost within the POD, right after the API call was completed. The pod gets restarted every time around 1 minute:

[image]

[image]

I could understand that it crashed during execution. But how the POD can be restarted after a minute of having completed its task. And again, the same resources, same codebase on a different cluster works without problem.

Comment: You need to double check everything between UAT and PROD: probes, ports, image used, setup in general. There are no miracles. Also as a check you can deploy a pod into the cluster and try to curl directly to pod to check if it actually works as expected.

Comment: Already tried all of that, that's why I came here. Curl directly to pod works as expected.

Comment: You are saying it works fine on a different cluster. What's the difference between them? Is k8s version the same? It's very difficult to play a guess game.

Comment: I know, sorry about that, but it's the scenario I was dealing with. Two identical clusters, same code base. One worked, one didn't. It appears that a logging (Winston) function in PROD, was processing more information than in UAT, and was causing the POD to stop responding. We still trying to confirm that to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there were two parts for this.

I found a difference in one of the clusters (PROD), it had some limits via helm, that were not in place for (UAT):

```
resources:
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #   cpu: 500m
  #   memory: 1000Mi
  # requests:
  #   cpu: 125m
  #   memory: 250Mi
```

And, in addition to that, the process running on the pod of the PROD cluster, had a process that got hung because of the amount of information it was trying to log. The same process didn't hang con UAT, because of the much smaller input of data it had.